Disable TipMix and x-ms-routing-name cookie from website
we’ve picked up two new cookies on our site, TipMix and x-ms-routing-name after checking we found that these are related to Azure and started when we transferred traffic to a different environment. Currently, we are not transferring any traffic but these cookies are still dropping.
I tried checking on azure but couldn't find anything related to cookies.Is there any way to disable them or check why they are still coming?

You can disable the Session affinity in the configuration section of the Azure App service.

After disabling the session affinity, restart the app and check once.


TipMix and x-ms-routing-name after checking we found that these are related to Azure

Yes, both the cookies are related to Azure Environment.

check why they are still coming?

Initially my App don't have any deployment slots.


You can see there are no cookies related to TipMix and x-ms-routing-name.



I have created a new slot and set the Traffic% to 0(or some other no.).



Now you can see the new cookies are created.


I don`t see any cookies created for newly created slot.Cookies are available only for the production slot.

I tried to change the Traffic%, still no change.


As per this Blog,

TiPMix  – Used in Azure to pin a user session to a deployment slot during deployments.


x-ms-routing-name  – Used in Azure during deployments to route to deployment slots.

Thanks @Aleksei Chudinov  for the comments.
As per the comments it is clear that you need to set the  production slot traffic% to null.

To disable it you need to set the traffic% of production slot to null.

AFAIK, this is not directly possible from Portal.

I have tried to route the traffic to other slots, but sill the production slot is showing 0 value.



You can refer the GitHub which address the same issue.
